# Event listeners only work once in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener, event-listener

I want to attach event listeners to every cell in each of the two grids so that when I click on my  opponent's grid (and it's my turn) I can attack with func() which also flips turn. Then when my opponent
clicks on my grid (and it's their turn) they attack with func() and switch turn back to me.
The issue with this code is the event listeners seem to only attach once per grid. So I can attack once and my opponent can attack me once and then I can't attack again.
How could I solve this?

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#enemyGrid .cell");
for (let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (turn === 0) {
            //do stuff
            func(); //sets turn=1
        }
    });
}
const cellsMe = document.querySelectorAll("#meGrid .cell");
for (let i = 0; i < cellsMe.length; i++) {
    cellsMe[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (turn === 1) {
            //do stuff
            func(); //sets turn =0
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: you are binding tons of events over and over again. The code just keeps selecitng elements and looping to attach events over and over again. There is zero reason to use a while loop. It is not sitting there in the loop waiting for the `won` boolean to flip. Whatever `func` is doing should call the next step when the player wins.

Comment: In other words, the players implement the "loop" by continuing to play.  Under that structure, all the cells get the same event listener, setup only once. That function changes the games state according to the event.target, evaluates whether the new state is a winning state, flips the turn variable if there's no winner, and then updates the DOM to indicate the new state.

Comment: I edited my code after your advice and I have a new question. I edited the original post

Comment: You attach the event handler once but the function will be called every time the corresponding event occurs. The problem is the if condition that will be true once only of course. I suggest you also to add the event parameter so that you will know the exact HTML element firing the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple demo trying to accomplish what you are expecting.

I kept the structure of your dom and crafted a js function that will populate the .grid elements with a given number of cells that will be styled in a grid layout.

To those cells will be later added a click event listener with no discrimination of player, that will check the user having the latest move and will prevent the same player to pick a cell before the other player made its choice.

Everytime a player picks a cell, the turn counter increments, the background of the picked cell turns to red and the event gets printed on console

```js
//build the grids
const grids = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
grids.forEach(grid => populateGrid(grid, 10));

//populates the given grid in target with size*size cells
function populateGrid(target, size) {
  for (let i = 0; i < size * size; i++) {
    const cell = document.createElement('div');
    cell.classList.add('cell');
    target.appendChild(cell);
  }
}

//function called each time the click event occurs on cells
let turn = 0;
let latestMoveBy = '';
function playerMove(player, cell){
  if(latestMoveBy == player)
    return;
  turn++;
  cell.classList.add('picked');
  latestMoveBy = player;
  console.log(`Player: ${player} picked a cell at turn: ${turn}`);
}

//pick all the .cell elements inside a .grid
document.querySelectorAll(".grid .cell")
  //and for each one of them attach a click event handler
  .forEach( cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      const clickedCell = event.target;
      const player = clickedCell.parentElement.dataset.player;
      playerMove(player, clickedCell);
    });
  });
```

```css
.grid>.cell {
  background:  darkgray;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, auto);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  width: fit-content;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.picked {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="enemyGrid" class="grid" data-player="player1">
</div>

<hr>

<div id="meGrid" class="grid" data-player="player2">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. With a few adjustments to my original code, this logic works.